# Unlimited WordPress Menu

Tags: menus

I am limited to like 80 menus. My menu consists of 1000 menus. How can I increase the limitation of Appearance > Menu

I tried modifying the php.ini (using reseller account) and increase the `max_var`, but that didn't work

Comment: ya mean 'max_input_vars' ?

Comment: This is a weak point in WordPress. In theory, it is being addressed by this [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134)

Comment: yes Tom, that is what i meant